# I want to assign labels 0/1 to pandas datafrmae according to columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am fairly new to python.I am trying to assign labels in a pandas dataframe.This is how my dataframe looks :
final.head(3)

```
Match Team1 Team2 winner       
A       2     3      3             
B       1     2      1            
C       3     1      1
```

I want to create a new column which demonstrates who won the match.As in if Team1 wins the game label should be 0 and if Team2 wins the game label should be 1.
Expected outcome should be : -

```
Match Team1 Team2 winner label      
A       2     3      3     1        
B       1     2      1     0       
C       3     1      1     1
```

Please tell me how should i proceed.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The labels are wrong?

Comment: no the labels are correct.. numpy is needed here.

Comment: @YatishKadam ??

Comment: If Team1 wins the game label should be 0 and if team2 wins the game label should be 1 .labels are correct

Comment: @yatu so one of the ways to do this is to create a serialized list using numpy and then pass it as a new column to the df.. Thats why i suggested numpy as a good tag for it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label is essentially whether winner is the same with Team2. So you can do

```
final['label'] = final['winner'].eq(final['Team2']).astype(int)
```

Or if you insisted on `numpy`, then according to your logic:

```
final['label'] = np.where(final['Team1'].eq(final['winner']), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[(conditional), 'column_name'] = 'value'
```

So for you:

```
final.loc[(df['Team1']>df['Team2']), 'label'] = 'Team1 Won'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this also using where

```py
df["label"] = np.where(df["winner"]==df["Team1"], 0, 1)
```