# Calculate Euclidean distance between two points in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, euclidean-distance

My data in a pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
Sample  Point   Axis  Value1    Value2

S1       P1      X     1.2       1.28
S1       P1      Y     3.4       3.6
S1       P1      Z     1.4       1.6
S1       P2      X     1.2       1.23
S1       P2      Y     -3.4      -3.5
S1       P2      Z     1.4       1.48
S1       P3      X     1.65      1.68
S1       P3      Y     0.8       0.96
S1       P3      Z     2.0       1.9
S1       P4      X     1.65      1.65
S1       P4      Y     -0.8      -0.88
S1       P4      Z     2.0       2.2
```

Expected dataframe after calculating distance between P1,P2 and P3,P4 for S1

```
Sample  Point   Axis  Value1    Value2

    S1       P1      X     1.2       1.28
    S1       P1      Y     3.4       3.6
    S1       P1      Z     1.4       1.6
    S1       P2      X     1.2       1.23
    S1       P2      Y     -3.4      -3.5
    S1       P2      Z     1.4       1.48
    S1       P3      X     1.65      1.68
    S1       P3      Y     0.8       0.96
    S1       P3      Z     2.0       1.9
    S1       P4      X     1.65      1.65
    S1       P4      Y     -0.8      -0.88
    S1       P4      Z     2.0       2.2
    S1       D1            6.8       7.1
    S1       D2            1.6       1.86
```

I want to calculate Euclidean distance between the points (P1, P2)
and (P3,P4) for both value1 and value2 and insert it back to the dataframe as new points D1 and D2
D1 is Euclidean distance between P1, P2 
D2 is Euclidean distance between P3, P4

Here I have shown only one sample (S1) with 4 points (P1,P2,P3,P4), but in my data I have multiple samples (S1,S2,S3....etc) with the same four points(P1,P2,P3,P4)
I want to apply my calculation to each sample.

I am not sure how to achieve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Euclidean distance of points coordinates in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147379/euclidean-distance-of-points-coordinates-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @AnnZen I am not sure how to assign labels D1 and D2 and insert it back to the dataframe

Comment: would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58137731/i-want-to-assign-labels-0-1-to-pandas-datafrmae-according-to-columns?r=SearchResults&s=1|88.3983

Comment: @AnnZen its adding a new column, i am looking to add rows to the existing columns

Comment: @AnnZen I was able to calculate the distance between any two points, but i am not able to apply that to all samples and insert it back to the dataframe as a new row with a new point label , any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know.